Enigma Implementation Question
How do rings affect encryption?
My current understanding is that it is just an offset, but I am having difficulty understanding the output of a test case.
TEST(ExampleTests, TestEnigmaOneRotorWRing) {
  // Plugboard: C->C
  // Rotor I: C->E
  // Reflector: E->A    
  // Reverse Rotor I: A->V
  // Plugboard: V->V
  const char *rotors[] = {ROTOR_I};
  size_t rings[] = {1};
  size_t inits[] = {1};
  Enigma *enigma = new_Enigma(1, rotors, rings, inits, I_UKW_A, 0, NULL);
  char encrypt[] = "\0\0\0\0";
  encrypt_Enigma(enigma, encrypt, "C");
  ASSERT_STREQ(encrypt, "V");
  free_Enigma(enigma);
} 

I_UKW_A "EJMZALYXVBWFCRQUONTSPIKHGD"

ROTOR_I "EKMFLGDQVZNTOWYHXUSPAIBRCJ,Q"

Q is the notch.
There is nothing in the plugboard.
There is only 1 rotor.
I_UKW_A is a reflector.
How does A become V?

Sometimes an image can tell thousands words, see https://brej.org/enigma/Image10.gif

it's unclear what "just an offset" means to you.  Changing the ring setting of a rotor has the same effect on the permutation it implements as as rotating the rotor.

I agree that indicator/ring setting is just an offset, but there is a little more to it. If I will rephrase your question as "How do indicators affect encryption?" Then, your computation,
  // Rotor I: C->E
  // Reflector: E->A    
  // Reverse Rotor I: A->V

is absolutely correct. I am second guessing that you might have mixed up some variables.

Indicator setting $n_i = 1$ has the effect of turning the wiring core one
step forward.
Ring setting $n_r = 1$ has the effect of turning the wiring core one step backward.
Their combined effect on the wiring core is $n = n_i-n_r$. In your case $n_i=1, n_r=0$, we have $n=1$.
Since there is no rotor to the left of Rotor I, turnover notch† is not relevant.

Let cyclic permutation $\rho = \mathtt{(ABCDE\ FGHIJ\ KLMNO\ PQRST\ UVWXY\ Z)}$.
You have correctly computed forward $\rho R \rho^{-1} = \mathtt{(DKSOGPWQTZ)(AJMV)(BLNX)(CEF)(HU)(IY)(R)}$ and reverse permutations $\rho R^{-1} \rho^{-1} = \mathtt{(DZTQWPGOSK)(AVMJ)(BXNL)(CFE)(HU)(IY)(R)}$ .
I find the following diagram useful.
       C E
       | ^
       v |
ρ = (ABCDE FGHIJ KLMNO PQRST UVWXY Z)
        |  ^
        |  |
        |  +------------------+
        +--------------------+|
                             ||
                             v|
R = (AELTPHQXRU)(BKNW)(CMOY)(DFG)(IV)(JZ)(S)

      E
      |
      v
U = (AE)(BJ)(CM)(DZ)(FL)(GY)(HX)(IV)(KW)(NR)(OQ)(PU)(ST)
     |
     v
     A

     A                        V
     |                        ^
     v                        |
ρ = (ABCDE FGHIJ KLMNO PQRST UVWXY Z)
      |                        ^
      |                        |
      |             +----------+
      +----------+  |
                 |  |
                 v  |
R = (AELTPHQXRU)(BKNW)(CMOY)(DFG)(IV)(JZ)(S)

† The notch position of Rotor I is $\mathtt{Y}$. Minus 8, we have turnover position $\mathtt{Q}$. After turning over the next rotor, $\mathtt{R}$oyal shows in the indicator window. I keep track only the turnover positions.
